# Display files date last modified in Blueimp

Tags: javascript, html, blueimp

I am trying to display last modified date of files uploaded in index.html.

I've tried the following:

```
<td>
    <span class="date">{%=file.lastModifiedDate%}</span>
</td>
```

This works fine on line 154, which is part of the files available for upload :element.

But it doesn't work when I add the above code in line 198, which is part of the files available for download element.

The code is in index.html -> https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/index.html

Can anyone help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a for loop from line 146 to 174 which get `file` object from `files` array but these are uploaded files. The line you are getting is for files available for download. That is the reason why you can't get the date since there are no file available for download at the point of time.

```
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">  
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
            <tr class="template-upload fade">
                <td>
                    <span class="preview"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                    <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="size">Processing...</p>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                        <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                            <span>Start</span>
                        </button>
                    {% } %}
                    {% if (!i) { %}
                        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                            <span>Cancel</span>
                        </button>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% } %}
```

Comment: So... how do i get it to display last mod. date for files available for download?